# How to delete/remove the word from array which is next to another word in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Im having an array like below:

```
["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT ", "e"]
```

On that how to remove the element next to NOT? I have shown static example. values in the array is dynamic.  i have to find the NOT operator and i have to delete the next word of NOT in all the array.

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected output? Also, what do you have so far?

Comment: expected output should be ["a", " OR ", "bc cd"] and i have tried find_element_after, delete_at, index

Comment: What should be the expected output of `["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT ", "e", "f", "g"]`??

Comment: @Surya It should delete all the element next to NOT

Comment: @user7348784: "It should delete all the element next to NOT" - that was not the question. The question was: what's the __expected output__? Post the output.

Comment: @user7348784: hint: "next to NOT" doesn't mean "after NOT". It means "adjacent to NOT". As such, "all elements next to NOT" doesn't make sense. That's why providing output is important. It lets us ignore mistakes in the wording.

Comment: in conjunction with @Surya how about `["a", " AND ", "z", " NOT ", "cd", " OR ", "r", " AND ", "db", " NOT ", "c"]` what is the expectation. You said this is dynamic but have not provided other examples, a use case or even the desired output. Please explain further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
arr = ["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT ", "e"]
```

**Method 1**: Takes about O(n) time complexity

```
new_arr = []
i = 0
while i < arr.length
 break if arr[i].strip == 'NOT' # or arr[i] != ' NOT '
 new_arr << arr[i]
 i += 1
end
```

**Method 2**: Again O(n)

```
new_arr = []
arr.each do |a|
  break if a.strip == 'NOT' # or arr[i] != ' NOT '
  new_arr << a
end
```

**Method 3**: Takes about O(n), but since the index method has to find the index of ' NOT ' and then yield the value to form range, it would be running 2 subsequent loops.

```
arr[0...arr.index(' NOT ')] # NOTE 3 dots
```

Also, I would avoid using Method 3, as `arr.index(' NOT ')` would return nil if there is no `' NOT '` in array, which will lead to a bad range exception.

Comment: your complexity estimation is off, in the last case. It's still O(N). Can you find the mistake? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Added detailed information, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-take_while):

```
arr.take_while { |str| str != ' NOT ' }
 #=> ["a", " OR ", "bc cd"]
```

Comment: IMO, this is a great answer. Keep it up.

Comment: We need `take_until`, for symmetry! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply provide range to array after [`find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index)

```
def delete_after(element, array)
  if (ind = array.find_index(element)).present?
    array[0...ind]
  else
    array
  end
end

arr = ["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT ", "e"]
delete_after(' NOT ', arr) # => ["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT "]
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  ohh yes, it doesn't modify itself, thanks :)

Comment: This will not give desired result. Use 3 dots: `...` as OP wants `["a", " OR ", "bc cd"]`, not - `["a", " OR ", "bc cd", " NOT "]`

Comment: @Surya yeah, I saw *next to NOT* and provided the solution, thanks though